# Is variance computed on weekly basis the same as variance computed on daily basis?

Tags: distributions, variance, uniform-distribution

I have a proportion value computed on a weekly basis with 95% confidence interval. Now I want to get the proportion on a daily basis, instead. Assuming the values are uniformly distributed, I divided my proportion into 5 (that's for 5 days). Will my variance stay the same?

Comment: Q is unclear. Do you mean variance of observed continuous proportions? or variance of estimated mean proportions?